# Why does the Silver Lucky Charm work differently for me and my friend?

Tags: atomas

I  play Atomas  with my friend and we compete for the highest score and we both use the Silver Lucky Charm which is meant to start you at Magnesium and I do start at Magnesium but my friend uses it and starts around Potassium.

Does anyone know why this happened?